Publish ASP.NET app without certain folders
I have a csproj with some folders with code from different clients.
When i publish my app i get something like this:

Client1Folder
Client2Folder
Client3Folder
Client3Folder2
SomeCommonFilesAndFolders
SomeFileThatNeedToBeDeleted

So in order to give it to client 3 i have to delete some files and end like this:

Client3Folder
Client3Folder2
SomeCommonFilesAndFolders

Whats the best way to aproach this?
I searched something like project configuration like "Debug" and "Release" but i dont know if thats ok and how to specify the folders.

You can add a configuration per client and then in your csproj do something like this:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Client3|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Client3\</OutputPath>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>SomeFileThatNeedToBeDeleted</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Client1Folder;Client2Folder</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>

Publish
dotnet publish -c Client3

